# Calling setAdapter() in another method doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I wanted to call setAdapter() in another method but on the same class/activity. However, it gives me a null pointer exception. I have a Listview lv=null; as a field.

When setAdapter() is inside the onCreate(), it does work:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new SemToGradeLoader(this).execute();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grade_book);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grade_list);
        reloadListView();
CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_grade, rowItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

When setAdapter is inside the reloadListView(), it doesn't work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new SemToGradeLoader(this).execute();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grade_book);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.grade_list);
    reloadListView();

}
```

Here is my reloadListView():

```
private void reloadListView() {

    try {

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(subjects[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }
        CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_grade, rowItems);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

    }
```

Comment: May you post the complete code of your class, and the code of your layout ?

Comment: is reloadListView called from any other place in your class?

Comment: What is `subjects` and where is it initialized? It doesn't appear to be initialized before you call this function. If that's not the issue then please post the logcat output so we can see exactly where it is `null`.

Comment: @Gaëtan don't suggest to post the whole class in this situation...we may get hundreds of unnecessary lines of code. Start with stacktrace and see what is relevant. Also, xml probably doesn't help here since the `ListView` is getting initialized properly in `onCreate()`

Comment: i dont have a problem about the rowitems, the items are properly stored as I checked in the debugger. Im getting a nullpointerexception in the setAdapter()

Comment: @Rich no, it is a method  on the same class

Comment: So when you debug and set a breakpoint you see that `lv` is `null` inside that function?

Comment: Could you please post the logcat too? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is :

```
new SemToGradeLoader(this).execute();
```

Is it an async task or something?

From its completed method, are you trying to access the listview by calling reloadListView() or something?